# deploying flex applications

Tags: apache-flex, performance, deployment

I have a Flex application which has to be deployed in some server. The typical form of access would be invoking the URL. How do i go about it?
Should I have multiple instances of the applications running on the same server/ deploying the application in diff servers and using a load balancer for routing?
If i must have multiple instances, how to do that?
On a given day, the application is expected to get around 2000-3000 hits. What are all the factors to be kept in mind while deployment?
Any pointers would be helpful.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually a bit unsure what specifically you're asking, so I'll take your questions one by one.

> I have a Flex application which has to
>   be deployed in some server. The
>   typical form of access would be
>   invoking the URL. How do i go about
>   it?

Put your SWF files on a web server.  For best results export a release build first.  Flash Builder makes this easy.

> Should I have multiple instances of
>   the applications running on the same
>   server/ deploying the application in
>   diff servers and using a load balancer
>   for routing?

Probably not, but it depends.  A SWF is just a binary asset.  As far as the server is concerned it is no different from a JPG, gif, or PNG file.  Whether or not you need a load balancer to serve the SWF depends on the size of the SWF, the amount of simultaneous hits you expect, other traffic on the server, bandwidth of your hosting provider, and probably a whole slew of other considerations that escape me at the moment.

If your SWF is making calls to the server--very common in Flex Applications--that may also be a consideration.

> If i must have multiple instances, how
>   to do that?

If you have multiple instances of what?  Of the SWF?  Why would you need to do that?  As I said, as far as the server is concerned a SWF is just a binary asset.  In theory you could keep as many copies of the file on your server as you want, in practice most people just use a single one.

> On a given day, the application is
>   expected to get around 2000-3000 hits.
>   What are all the factors to be kept in
>   mind while deployment? Any pointers
>   would be helpful.

That strikes me as low traffic site; however it depends what you're doing.

Despite my answer, I have to vote to close as your questions is vague and ambiguous.  I'm not sure what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss a basic information on your application.
As long as you create Flex/Flash application and you put them on your server they will always  be SWF file executed Client Side.
So i think you don't have to  wonder on the workload of your server because isn't your server that run the application but the Client PC.
As long as your server can manage 2000/3000 hit per day you can be quite sure that alway will run smootly.

Claudio.